# *ngIf length doesnt work, but displaying good value

Tags: angular

In my template:

```
{{(services | async)?.length}}
```

returns "3" - the good number of items in array.
But when im using *ngIf:

```
<ion-text *ngIf="(services | async)?.length == 3">{{(services | async)?.length}}</ion-text>
```

display nothing. I dont understand why *ngIf returns false?

Comment: Post your code related to services

Comment: `  collection$(path: string, query?) {
    return this.afs
      .collection(path, query)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        })
      );
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the second subscription isn't performed before your observable emits the first value with attribute length equals to 3 so condition becomes true and the second expression gets evaluated, try to assign the (services | async)?.length to another variable with higher scope and then use it in both test and display.

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="(services | async)?.length as length">
    <ion-text *ngIf=" length=== 3">{{length}}</ion-text>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: `ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: missing name after . operator`